response cookie not persisting with Elysia & TRPC
So picked up Bun recently, have setup Remix + Elysia wrapped TRPC + Prisma to build out a project.
I've created a pretty simple login system with the intention to implement the JWT cookie flow. However I'm running into a problem where the cookie won't persist even though it's present in the response & acknowledged by network tools as a cookie. It just refuses to appear in storage & isn't sent with the next request.
For context, here's the network info
Headers

Cookies

Stored cookies

I've got the below as my Elysia setup
const CONFIG = {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3000,
  protocol: 'http'
}

new Elysia()
  .use(
    cors({
      credentials: true,
      origin: true,
    }
  ))
  .use(
    trpc(
      router,
      {
        createContext,
      }
    )
  )
  .listen({
    hostname: CONFIG.host,
    port: CONFIG.port,
  })

console.log(`listening on http://${CONFIG.host}:${CONFIG.port}`)

with the createContext simply being to pass context through
export async function createContext(opts: FetchCreateContextFnOptions) {

  return opts
}

then in my trpc login query I've got
ctx.resHeaders.set(
  'Set-Cookie', 
  'hello=world; SameSite=Lax; Path=/; Max-Age=3600; HttpOnly'
)


Managed to get it working after test hitting the actual trpc endpoint and seeing the cookie get set as it should which led me down the thought process that it's a problem with the trpcClient setup.
Included the credentials with the fetch associated with the trpcClient
export const client = createTRPCClient<Router>({
  links: [
    httpBatchLink({
      fetch: (url, init) => fetch(url, {
        ...init,
        credentials: 'include'
      }),
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/trpc'
    }),
  ]
})

and tweaked the cors plugin config for the server
new Elysia()
  .use(
    cors({
      allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type'],
      credentials: true,
      origin: /^http:\/\/127\.0\.0\.1:8080$/,
    }
  ))
  .use(
    trpc(
      router,
      {
        createContext,
      }
    )
  )
  .listen({
    hostname: CONFIG.host,
    port: CONFIG.port,
  })

